# Can I "convert" ParseTree to CommonTree in ANTLR?

Tags: java, antlr4, parse-tree

I want to construct subtrees of a ParseTree, but the only class that contains an insertChild(index,Object) method seems to be CommonTree, and I cannot pass a RuleContext type object, because it tries convert it to Tree object, and i get "java.lang.ClassCastException: Java8Parser$ClassDeclarationContext cannot be cast to org.antlr.runtime.tree.Tree" exception.

Any Ideas? Thanks. (Edit: added the code)

```
private void getSubtrees(ParseTree tree){
    CommonTree commonTree = new CommonTree();
    setRecursiveDescendants(commonTree, tree);
}

private CommonTree setRecursiveDescendants(CommonTree commonTree,ParseTree parseTree){
    int n = parseTree.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            commonTree.insertChild(i, parseTree.getChild(i);
            setRecursiveDescendants(commonTree, parseTree.getChild(i));
        }
        return commonTree;
}
```

Comment: You clearly have some code if you have an exception. Can you edit your question to include what you have so far please?

Comment: CommonTree is a class of ANTLR3. Is your grammar ANTLR3?

Comment: I'm using ANTLR4, and my grammar is ANTLR4

Comment: I cannot find common tree in ANTLR4. Can you give a hint in which package/artifact?

Comment: It's in  org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree;

Comment: It does not exist in ANTLR4. If you only want to copy a Tree, than `ParserRuleContext` should be sufficient. It does support an `addChild` method (for your short snippet this would be ok).

Comment: I actually did something like that in the meantime, and it works.